# i want to use different menu as page

Tags: wordpress

I have a page made in wordpress.
The page contains 4 different menus but they have common menu item like "About us". 
My problem is that when I click "About us" in any menu ,I want to open the elements of the menu which I clicked.

for example:
Menü - 1 :
About Us - Hair Transplant - Methods

Menu - 2:
About Us - Eye Care - Methods

for example: When I click "About us"  on Menu -2 , I want to show About us  on Menu - 2,
How can I do it ?

Thank you

Comment: Go to appearance -> Menus and simply create a new menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want  " The page contains 4 different menus but they have common menu item like "About us". My problem is that when I click "About us" in any menu ,I want to open the elements of the menu which I clicked."

The you need to build different  page or post. If you build post then you need to creat 4 different category. And add those category on your menu.

Or;

If you build different page then you need to copy page link and then pate the link on your costume menu link.